# Why is LogMeIn via Ubuntu so slow to refresh?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, plugins, logmein

At work I use logmein.com to do remote support to many users.

When I do this on my Ubuntu box, it connects, but then it reloads the page on every mouse click or event.  How do I make this work more like using logmein.com while on Mac or Windows.

Thanks.

Using Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the LogMeIn Linux plugin from their [Labs](https://secure.logmein.com/US/labs/).

I have a nasty feeling that it won't install on 64bit Firefox though, so you'll either need to install 32bit FF, or the Java plugin on 64 bit. More info in their [Support Forums](http://community.logmein.com/t5/Labs-Betas-and-Tech-Previews/64-bit-Linux-Support/m-p/23423).

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems installing Java 64 but I have found that just installing flash player plugin for Mozilla improves logmein performance.

Still not quite what I am used to but it is at least somewhat usable now.